# How to re allow user to delete text and not add characters?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text were users can type in a max character of 100, once it is 100 the edit text is set to `comments.setKeyListener(null);`but the problem is I want to allow the user to delete some of the characters to re edit it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new TextWatcher

```
TextWatcher commentsWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int c = 100 - comments.getText().length();

        if (c < 0) {
            // if the length is 100 delete the last char
            comments.setText(comments.getText().toString().substring(0, comments.getText().length() - 1));
            // if you delete the last char the cursor will be moved on
            // the start of your EdidText, so you must move it on the end
            comments.setSelection(comments.getText().length());
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

and then call it on you EditText like this

```
 comments.addTextChangedListener(commentsWatcher);
```

Comment: thank you, yes I already have this code but lacking this part only `comments.setText(comments.getText().toString().substring(0, comments.getText().length() - 1));`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the recommended way to set the maximum length for user input. You should use the [`android:maxLength`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength) xml attribute or add a [`LengthFilter`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/InputFilter.LengthFilter.html) with [`setFilters()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter[]%29).